# How to create a second fax user extension for Outbound Fax API in the RingCentral sandbox?

Tags: api, fax, ringcentral

I am using the RingCentral developer sandbox account and want to create a second fax extension. I'm using the following API:

https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/:accountid/extension?page=1&perPage=100

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to get all extensions which have the ability to send outbound fax? What do you mean by "sub account"?

Comment: I am trying to send FAX from sandbox account but there is only one main phone number I want to send FAX using multiple phone numbers. My RingCentral account doesn't allow me to add more phone numbers.

Comment: You can add several numbers to the sandbox account including `VoiceFax` numbers to that handle both voice and fax. How many fax numbers do you want to send from and why is sending from more than one important?

Comment: I try to use the following link to add numbers in sandbox "https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev/topics/how-to-add-users-extensions-to-https-service-devtest-ringcentral-com-for-developing-apps-in-sandbox-environment", but there is no such kind of configuration provided in our demo environment. I have multiple phone number in Users with Extension section but in the link it is showing that you have to use Unassigned Extension.                                       In our live account, we have multiple phone number configured so each user has its own number.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my answer below on how to add a new user extension with fax sending and receiving abilities below. I also updated the question to make this a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a user with fax sending abilities to your Sandbox Account using the following two steps below. If your account has fax capabilities, your new user will automatically have fax permissions. See below on how to check if your account has fax capabilities.

As a note, RingCentral numbers can be used for fax, voice and SMS so this these steps will also allow you to send voice and SMS.

**1) Create Unassigned Extension**

Create an extension by logging into the Online Account Portal (https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com) and navigating to the `Admin Portal`. From there, navigate to `Users` > `+ Add User` and complete the wizard.

- [KB Article: Adding User Extensions to your RingCentral Account](https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Adding-Extensions-via-Web)
- [Video: Create User in Developer Sandbox - Part 1 of 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DL_AEmncy00)

If you don't know what area code to select, you can select one that matches your existing sandbox number which should be at the top of the page after you log in. Use this [Area Code data set](https://github.com/grokify/datasets/blob/master/areacode/areacodes.tsv) to identify the area code state and select that state. If you have questions on selecting a number, contact RingCentral on [Glip](https://glipped.herokuapp.com) or at devsupport@ringcentral.com.

**2) Assign Extension to User**

After completing the above, you will see your entry in `Users` > `Unassigned Extensions`. You can add a name and email address to the unassigned extension via the Online Account Portal or via the SCIM API.

- [KB Article: Activating an Unassigned User Extension](https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/How-to-Activate-User-Extensions-Creating-Password-Security-Question-and-Express-Setup-2013)
- [Video: Create User in Developer Sandbox - Part 2 of 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeGVd4yiR9w)
- [API Reference: SCIM Create User API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefCreateUser)

**Verify Your Account Can Send Faxes**

In addition to the above, you should verify that your account can send and receive faxes. Most RingCentral accounts can but I'm adding this here for completeness. To check if your account has the fax feature call the following API:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/service-info
```

You will receive a response like the following. Look for the feature with `"featureName": "Fax"` which should have `enabled` set to `true`. I've cut out some info for brevity so the relevant parts stand out more.

```
{
  "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/service-info",
  "servicePlanName": "RingCentral Sandbox Office 4 lines Enterprise Edition (Free)",
  "brand": {...},
  "servicePlan": {...},
  "billingPlan": {...},
  "serviceFeatures": [
    {
      "featureName": "Fax",
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "featureName": "FaxReceiving",
      "enabled": true
    }
  ],
  "limits": {...}
}
```